# Effective search in sorted string vector

Tags: c++, search, stdvector

I have a long vector of strings. Example:

```
std::string data;
data.push_back("abc");
data.push_back("bcd");
//...
data.push_back("zze");
data.push_back("zzz");
```

The strings in the vector are alphabetically sorted.

I understand I can use `std::find` to find the existence and position of a string in the `std::vector`. But since my vector is alphabetically sorted, is there an easy to implement and more effective method to check the existence of a value in the vector?

Comment: If you want to see if the value exists at all I'd recommend using [`std::binary_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) (but it returns a boolean rather than an iterator to the element found).

Comment: ... But `std::binary_search`'s cousin, `std::lower_bound`, can help with finding an iterator to the element you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the container is sorted, you might use [std::binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

> Checks if an element equivalent to value appears within the range [first, last).

```
std::string some_value = "xyz";

const auto found =
    std::binary_search(std::cbegin(data), std::cend(data), some_value);
```

So `found` is `true` if `some_value` is found and `false` in the other case.

---

If you are interested in getting an iterator which points to the element you are looking for, then consider using [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
const auto it =
    std::lower_bound(std::cbegin(data), std::cend(data), some_value);

if (it != std::cend(data)) {
    // element is found, it points to this element
}
```

Comment: Looking at the criteria for sorted vector in the std::binary_search description, it looks like this only would work for vectors of numbers. How does binary_search "understand" the alphabetic sorting?

Comment: @remi000 -- A `std::string` has an overloaded `<` operator.  The `std::binary_search` understands any type, as long as the type has a less-than comparitor that follows a strict-weak-ordering.

Comment: @remi000 "this only would work for vectors of numbers" - not at all, it would work for any type which is comparable via `<`. Also note, that you might pass a custom predicate.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , just noticed you might want to update your last example? You say use lower_bound but it shows binary_search in the example.

Comment: Probably meant that for @EdgarRokyan.  Still, same thing is true for `lower_bound` -- if the type is comparable using `<`, then it will work.